# Liferay: How to use processAction or link jsp to action class

Tags: jsp, portlet, liferay-6

I am struggling hard to understand how JSP links to action.

I have `view.jsp`, `edit.jsp` and a Java class with `setVal` as its method

I have included following code in edit.jsp

```
<portlet:actionURL var="editURL" name="setVal">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/edit.jsp" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

And this in the form

```
action="<portlet:actionURL name="processAction">
```

Please guide me on what is the correct way to call action from JSP.

I am using Liferay6.1

Answer (score 0):

When you create a actionURL like,

```
<portlet:actionURL var="editURL" name="setVal">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/edit.jsp" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

your form should look like

```
<form action="<%=editURL%>">
....
...
..
.
</form>
```

and your portlet class should contain a method by name :

```
void setVal(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
......
....
}
```

Your way of using the created actionURL is wrong, please go through the basic portlet tutorial.